# Is it possible to wrap logrus.Logger functions without losing the line number prefix?

Tags: go, logging, callstack

When using the wrapped logrus function/logger, the logger prefixes all log lines with the file name and line number of the logger function call, for example:

```
INFO[0000]logging.go:39 myfolder/logging.Info()
```

If I wrap the log function like this, for instance:
package logging

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "os"
    "path"
    "runtime"
)

var (
    log *logrus.Logger
)

func init() {

    log = logrus.New()
    log.SetReportCaller(true)
    log.Formatter = &logrus.TextFormatter{
        CallerPrettyfier: func(f *runtime.Frame) (string, string) {
            filename := path.Base(f.File)
            return fmt.Sprintf("%s()", f.Function), fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", filename, f.Line)
        },
    }
}

func Info(args ...interface{}) {
        log.Info(args...)
}
```

Every line emitted by this function is going to be prefixed with the line number of the `logging function` call. That is as expected, but the desired behavior is for each line to be prefixed with the line number of the line where `Info` is called.

The Desired output should be :

```
INFO[0000]myfile.go:39 myfolder/myfile.myfunction()
```

Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to do it in the logrus. I had a similar requirement and ended up doing the following which worked for us.

```golang
package mylog

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

var logger = logrus.New()

func SetLogFormatter(formatter logrus.Formatter) {
    logger.Formatter = formatter
}

// Info logs a message at level Info on the standard logger.
func Info(args ...interface{}) {
    if logger.Level >= logrus.InfoLevel {
        entry := logger.WithFields(logrus.Fields{})
        entry.Data["file"] = fileInfo(2)
        entry.Info(args...)
    }
}

func fileInfo(skip int) string {
    _, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(skip)
    if !ok {
        file = "<???>"
        line = 1
    } else {
        slash := strings.LastIndex(file, "/")
        if slash >= 0 {
            file = file[slash+1:]
        }
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", file, line)
}
```

See if this or some variation of this works for your use case. I have removed the application-specific code from the code snippet above.

Comment: This worked for me,Thank you @mayank-patel . My suggestion would be you should also add this solution to [logrus github issue](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/issues/63) as that is the first google search result for this problem.

Comment: hi @mayank, what is the purpose of skip parameter in to Caller function ?

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that I am not misunderstanding so you want the "actual" path and line number where the logger was called. The code (*json format as an example*) below should give you want you want. If you want to add more info, such as the function name etc., just modify `caller()` method.

```golang
logrus.SetReportCaller(true)
// ...

logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.JSONFormatter{
    CallerPrettyfier:  caller(),
    FieldMap: logrus.FieldMap{
        logrus.FieldKeyFile: "caller",
    },
})
```

```golang
// caller returns string presentation of log caller which is formatted as
// `/path/to/file.go:line_number`. e.g. `/internal/app/api.go:25`
func caller() func(*runtime.Frame) (function string, file string) {
    return func(f *runtime.Frame) (function string, file string) {
        p, _ := os.Getwd()

        return "", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", strings.TrimPrefix(f.File, p), f.Line)
    }
}
```

```
{
  "caller": "/internal/controller/create.go:21",
  "level": "info",
  "msg": "i am a dummy log",
  "time": "2020-08-30T19:17:48+01:00"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. get caller information(like filename/lineno/func etc.) in your own wrapper log function like `wrapper.Infof()`.
2. put caller information into `Fields`.
3. implement your own `Formatter`, get caller information from `Fields`, and use it.